# programmatically login symfony2 after registration

Tags: symfony

i try to login the user manually after the registration with this code:

http://www.michelsalib.com/2011/04/pragmatically-authenticate-the-user-in-symfony2/

Its not working with the fresh created user, but when i login an other existing user after a userregistation, everything works fine.
I thought the user object isn't complete but i tried to read the registrerd user again and it doesn't work too.

Has anyone an idea what the problem is?

Thank you very much

Comment: It was my fault. an other developer implement the advcancedUserInterface and the function isAccountLocked() returns true. that's the reaon why the login failed... :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a new token and pass it to the security context.

```
// Create a new token
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $credentials, $providerKey, $user->getRoles());

// Retrieve the security context and set the token
$context = $this->container->get('security.context');
$context->setToken($token);
```

Comment: It's the same code like in my link and this is the code that doesn't work on this position.

Comment: I use this code in all my Symfony 2 application and had no problem.

Comment: me too, it was my fault, see my acomment on top.. :-/